# How to get weekday name from a date in informix sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, informix, weekday

I have a date column in a table which I have to return weekday name from it while I join it with another table.

Right now I get it as an int  `WEEKDAY(a.vila_date) weekdag`

```
SELECT years, software, vsnr, WEEKDAY(a.vila_date) weekdag,  a.vilatime
FROM  vila a, onta v
```

I want a result like
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday. Considering 1 = Monday and 0 = Sunday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `TO_CHAR()` function to format a DATE or DATETIME value or column into various formats including the full or abbreviated weekday name.

Example:

```
SELECT TODAY today, 
       WEEKDAY(TODAY) wday_num, 
       TO_CHAR(TODAY, "%a") wday_short,
       TO_CHAR(TODAY, "%A") wday_full
FROM systables 
WHERE tabid = 1;
```

Output:

```
today       06/04/2021      
wday_num    5
wday_short  Fri
wday_full   Friday
```

The documentation for the `TO_CHAR()` function can be found at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=dcf-char-function#ids_sqt_129 where you can also search for information on the GL_DATETIME and GL_DATE environment variable which list the formatting directives (such as "%a") that can be used.

Comment: Can we have it in local language also? I mean the weekday name in other languages

Comment: The language used for weekday names, format of a date and various other things are defined by the setting of the CLIENT_LOCALE environment variable which needs to be compatible with the locale used for the database. If not set this will default to en_US.819 as in the example shown.

Comment: We don't have CLIENT_LOCALE environment variable and I have no access to add it. Is there a workaround to do it in function or in the query?